# Как в Photoshop правильно работать с картинкой?

Tags: html, css, photoshop

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Сайт](http://f0186535.xsph.ru/one.html)

Обратите внимание на лого на сайте, там отчётливо виден фон у картинки, который не является белым.
Как сделать логу прозрачной?
Сохранил картинку в PNG.

Comment: Всё, что связано с вопросом, публикуйте в самом вопросе без сторонних ссылок.

Comment: Добавьте для примера кусок логотипа, как он отображается на сайте.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь инструментом "Волшебная палочка" для того, чтобы выделить лишний фон и удалите его. Если не удается за раз выделить всё, что необходимо удалить, зажмите Shift и выделяйте несколько областей. Мелочи можно подправить ластиком.

Answer (score 1):

Сменив разширение фон сам собой не убирается.
Его нужно убрать самостоятельно.
Самый простой вариант для Photoshop:волшебный ластик.
Туториал: http://psand.ru/kak-ubrat-belyiy-fon-u-izobrazheniya/